# Pointer to object inside of a map is invalid yet the object still exists (executable code example)

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, vector

This is a highly simplified version of code in a bigger project. I think I am demonstrating the problem... I hope. Basically, I want a `Task` object that holds information about what needs to happen to a file (a file is just a `string` filepath right now). Later in the program I need to associate a `Task` with an `item` object so I can see what happened to that `Task` to update the `item` object by reading the `Task`. The problem is that my pointer to the `Task` gets screwed up.

The `cout`s produce gibberish.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string getDir(string f)
{
    return "c:/";
}

class BatchFileChanger
{
public:

    struct Task
    {
        string origFile;
    };

    Task* addTask(string originalPath)
    {
        TASKS.push_back({});
        Task& t = TASKS.back();
        t.origFile = originalPath;
    
        taskMapNew[getDir(t.origFile)][t.origFile].push_back(&t);
    
        return &TASKS.back();
    }

    vector<Task> TASKS;

    //map of folder inside map of file of holding tasks
    //associates folder containing files which each file has one task
    //each file can only have one task
    //the reason for a map of vector of one task is to ensure a single task per file
    //so you can look up a file string and ensure there is only Task
    //ok i guess i could get rid of the vector...
    map<string, map<string, vector<Task*>>> taskMapNew;

};

int main()
{
    BatchFileChanger batch;
    
    batch.addTask("c:/a_file.wav");
    
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/a_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    
    batch.addTask("c:/b_file.wav");
    
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/a_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/b_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    
    batch.addTask("c:/c_file.wav");
    
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/a_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/b_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << batch.taskMapNew["c:/"]["c:/c_file.wav"][0]->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

alternative int main

```cpp
int main()
{
    BatchFileChanger batch;
    
    auto ptr1 = batch.addTask("c:/a_file.wav");
    
    cout << ptr1->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    
    auto ptr2 = batch.addTask("c:/b_file.wav");
    
    cout << ptr1->origFile << "\n";
    cout << ptr2->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    
    auto ptr3 = batch.addTask("c:/c_file.wav");
    
    cout << ptr1->origFile << "\n";
    cout << ptr2->origFile << "\n";
    cout << ptr3->origFile << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `taskMapNew[getDir(t.origFile)][t.origFile].push_back(&t);` -- Ask yourself "what happens to those pointers that you are storing when the vector resizes?"

Comment: Perhaps you should use `vector<Task*>` and dynamically allocate the tasks. Then you can return the task pointer, rather than the address of the vector element.